# Using an Egypt driver's license in California with a J-1 visa

Tags: driving-licenses, california, j1-visas, egypt

I have a driver license issued in my country (Egypt), can I use it in California? I'm staying with a J-1 visa.
My name is written in English but the expiration date is in Arabic numerals.

Answer (score 1):

[This California DMV page](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/hdbk/ca_dl) says:

> **Adults Visiting California**
>
> Visitors over 18 years old with a valid DL from their home state or country may drive in California without getting a California DL as long as their home state or country DL is valid.

Comment: Is he a visitor though?

Comment: We don't know. See this SE thread for more info about determining "residency" in California: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117728/driving-in-california-with-a-foreign-driver-license

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off getting a California license:

> Tourists may drive rental cars in California for one year as long as they have a valid driver’s license from their home country.  See theDepartment of Motor Vehicles (link is external) for complete details.

([Source](https://internationaloffice.berkeley.edu/living/driving))

Comment: Please add a reference to your claim. I don't see one in the quote.